# #have doesn't capture CLs of deleted files in Perforce

Tags: perforce

We are using the following P4 command for snapshot versioning.

```
p4 changes -m1 /path/to/files/...#have
```

I noticed that the above command doesn't capture CLs of deleted files if the CL is the head CL.

So it ends up having two artifacts with the same version but different files.

I was wondering how we can cover this edge case?

Comment: Are you using depot syntax or client syntax or local syntax in your filespec?

Answer (score 1):

This is an artifact of the fact that deleted files aren't synced to the client and will therefore never be included in #have.

If possible, the best way to address this IMO is to capture the changelist at the time you sync to the head revision.  Do:

```
p4 changes -m1 -ssubmitted /path/to/files/...
```

and then use that changelist to do:

```
p4 sync /path/to/files/...@CHANGE
```

Since submitted changelists are immutable (outside of edge cases like obliterate and +S files) you now have a guarantee that anyone else syncing to that same path@change will get the same set of revisions that's in your workspace.

Note that the `p4 changes` command *will* capture changelists with deleted revisions, even if those revisions are then skipped by the `p4 sync`!